# How does the Fire Rate stat in Fallout 4 translate to shots per second?

Tags: fallout-4

In Fallout 4, every weapon has a "Fire Rate" statistic. How does this statistic translate to rounds fired per second?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Fallout wikia provides a helpful explanation of Rate of Fire on [this Weapons page](https://fallout.fandom.com/wiki/Fallout_4_weapons).

The article explains:

> "The in-game given number gives the maximum cyclic number of shots/attacks per 10 seconds, without considering reloading.
>
> This is internally derived from the weapons attack delay rating divided by its speed rating. However, if a weapon is converted to automatic or bolt-action fire, the time between shots becomes derived purely from its speed and/or firing animation duration."

If that second part is unclear let me use some more definitions. From a [Creation Kit forum post](https://www.creationkit.com/fallout4/index.php?title=Talk:Weapons):

> "An Attack Delay limits rate of fire by requiring a specified amount of time to pass before the next shot can be fired. The Automatic and Bolt Action Flags disable Attack Delay.
>
> Speed affects the maximum rate of fire and controls the speed of the firing animation (normally). Higher Speed values than 1 divide the Attack Delay and lower Speed values than 1 multiply it."

In simpler terms, Attack Delay is a weapon's charge time, and Speed would be rate of fire if there was no Attack Delay (and no reloading).

To provide some examples:

2 Speed and a 1 second Attack Delay (1/2) makes a semi-automatic weapon fire a shot every 0.5 seconds.

0.5 Speed and a 1 second Attack Delay (1/0.5) makes a semi-automatic weapon fire a shot every 2 seconds.

---

This calculation `Attack Delay/Speed` returns Seconds Per Attack. `10 (seconds)/Seconds Per Attack` returns your Rate of Fire stat and is what's shown on your weapon's description.

Comment: The extra research from the Creation Kit is perfect, thank you. Unfortunately, I don't have a good enough gaming PC setup to run FO4 (I play on PS4), so as per my last experiments with the Creation Kit, I don't have that available to me.